# Primefaces - Datatable not updated when value change

Tags: firefox, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with primefaces and I'm having a problem when using p:dataTable.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="label" value="#{myBean.labels}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="dataTable" style="width: 350px;">    
   <p:ajax event="cellEdit"  listener="#{myBean.onEdit}" update=":messages" />
   <p:column headerText="Column 1" width="20">                  
        <h:outputText id="current" value="#{myBean.currentTimeMillis}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Column 2" width="150">
      <p:cellEditor>    
        <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText value="#{label.name}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
          <h:inputText value="#{label.name}"/>
        </f:facet>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I would like that when I update the value of the second column of a row, then the value of the first column of this row is updated with a new value (currentTimeMillis).

```
public void public void onEdit(CellEditEvent event) 
{    
   UIData table = (UIData) event.getComponent();
   String updateClientId = table.getClientId() + ":" + table.getRowIndex() + ":current";
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(updateClientId);
}
```

Although this method in being invoked the first column is not being updated. Why? It is not working only in Firefox. It works on IE and Chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sure the 'updateClientId' gets the right value? Try running your application in developer mode

Comment: Yes, sure it is ok. It only fails on firefox.

Comment: I have finally  used the datatable with a p:rowEditor, and now works ok in all browsers.

Comment: Then please use the 'firefox' tag to and mention that. This is very, very weird..., what does the network traffic show if the different browsers? Is it the same?